# Job Specific SVN Checkout Folder for Jenkins Continuous Integration Server

Tags: jenkins, svn, workspace

I just set up a new Jenkins CI Server. It is the latest version that I just installed yesterday. I have done several builds that work fine.

I have several different repos that it pulls from and builds. Most of them are for things like .NET projects that are easy to build anywhere, so they just get checked out and built in the workspace folder.

I have one older project, however, that has a lot of hard coded paths and the system used to build it is a big pain to change that. For this reason it needs to live specifically in C:\dev\ProjectName.

This project uses SVN as the source control.

Is there a way to configure this one job in Jenkins to point to that specific path as the checkout and build folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To choose a specific build workspace you can use 'Use custom workspace' option in General Section (you need to click 'Advanced' button to see this option):
[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!