# Unable to view screenshots in Jenkins reports

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, screenshot

My jenkins reports do not show the screenshots captured in the runs. (They are run on a MAC). However, when I run the same job locally (windows machine), the reports have the screenshots.

I see the error as below in the Jenkins report.
[image: Report missing screenshot]

When I try to open the image, It shows below. It's unable to find the path to the image actually.

```
Error : http://*****-mac:8080/job/***Test/job/******/ws/target/screenshots/2019-01-14/Sign%20In20190114154253.png

Actual: http://*****-mac:8080/job/***Test/job/******/HTML_20Report/target/screenshots/2019-01-14/Sign%20In20190114154253.png
```

[image: Screenshot URL]

I'm using the below code to capture the screenshot. It does capture the screenshots & I can see them in the actual location.
I don't know when I did a mistake, these images are not seen as links/not available in the report:

```
public void captureScreenshot() throws IOException {

    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String dateForScreenshots = dateFormat.format(date);
    File localScreenshots = new File(new File("target/screenshots"), dateForScreenshots);
    if (!localScreenshots.exists() || !localScreenshots.isDirectory()) {
        localScreenshots.mkdirs();
    }
    System.setProperty("org.uncommons.reportng.escape-output", "false");// this is to create a link in ReportNG
    File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    String destination = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/target/screenshots/" + dateForScreenshots + "/" + getDriver().getTitle() + Utils.generateRandomString() + ".png";
    File screenshotName = new File(destination);
    //Now add screenshot to results by copying the file
    FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, screenshotName);
    Reporter.log("<br>  <img src='" + destination + "' height='90' width='160' /><br>");
    Reporter.log("<a href=" + destination + "></a>");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this line

```
Error : http://*****-mac:8080/job/***Test/job/******/ws/target/screenshots/2019-01-14/Sign%20In20190114154253.png
```

I think that Jenkins cannot find the target branch in the workspace folder (`ws`). Probably you need to specify the workspace folder in the Jenkins job (as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54116129/10721592) answer) or just change the `destination` variable somehow to something like (added `/HTML_20Report`):

```
    String destination = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/HTML_20Report/target/screenshots/" + dateForScreenshots + "/" + getDriver().getTitle() + Utils.generateRandomString() + ".png";
```

Comment: Thank u.. i changed the final img src location used in the reported log.