# I want to change the custom workspace for every job in a view dynamically

Tags: jenkins

I have a repository from which we deploy the build, but since we have different code base(i.e repository), I need to change the custom workspace for every job in a view. So, is there a way to change the custom workspace for every job in a view?

Comment: This seems awkward.  Jenkins pulls down the artifacts it needs to work with into a workspace *per job*.  Are you reusing the same job for different artifacts?

Answer (score 0):

For different jobs you just can use `Custom workspace` option, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54116129/10721592) answer for details.
So, if I understand you correctly, you need to pass dynamic workspace for one job.

The best way to do that is to use [Jenkins pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/) and pass branch name as a build parameter.

For freestyle job probably you can use different sub-directories in the same workspace using `Git -> Additional Behaviours -> Check out to a sub-directory` option in **Source Code Management** tab and specify an input build parameter (`This project is parameterized` option) for the branch name, e.g., specify `REPOSITORY` parameter and pass it to `Check out to a sub-directory` option as `$REPOSITORY`.